# Bootstrap Carousel slideshow not functioning at all

Tags: carousel

I think I didn't miss anything. but not functioning. I've got this code from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/. I've just changed id value from carouselExampleIndicators to myCarousel. I had a look the similar question 'Boostrap carousel is not functioning'. Coundn't find any error.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bright Homepage</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="daynightstyle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
      interval: 2000,
      pause: "false"
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
  <h1><a href="index.html">BRIGHT'S HOMEPAGE</a></h1>
  <a href="aboutme.html">ABOUT ME</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="mycity.html">ABOUT MY CITY</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="mypodcast.html">ABOUT MY PODCASTS</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="mycampus.html">MY CAMPUS</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="myphotos.html">MY PHOTOS</a>
  <div id="ch_btn">
    <input type="button" value="night" onclick="nightDayHandler(this)">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h2>Welcome to My Home</h2>
  <h3>This is my home.</h3>
  <p>I want that my house should be a place where you feel most comfortable<br />
  A Stranger in My Home should be an exciting. Bring more people to my home. Enjoy your time on my Homepage</p>

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="images\boise_downtown.jpg" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="images\hilltop_town.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="images\koldalen.jpg" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="images\night_fog.jpg" alt="First slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: You can follow this pen to create your own: https://codepen.io/kravisingh/pen/pLGzgo

Comment: It works. I've only deleted script for carousel activation and added this( <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>). Where this one come from and what for?

Comment: I've solved the problem added following code before head tag. See the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've added following code. it works.

```
<style>
 .carousel-item > img {
   position: relative;
   min-width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
</style>
```